# Recursive query aborted

Tags: mysql

I have one table in which I have details regarding family members like spouse, father and mother.
Now based on this I need to fetch data like this:

```
Spouse

children

children spouse and then their children
```

English is not my native language. Please forgive me for any mistake and I hope I am clear. Otherwise please let me know.

So for this I have created this recursive query (First time I am using this).
For some nodes it's showing the data but for some other nodes it's showing errors like Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations.
I tried increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.

Here is my query

```
WITH RECURSIVE family_tree1_hierarchy AS
( SELECT rsc.id,rsc.Name,rsc.spouse,0 AS lvl FROM main_table AS rsc
WHERE rsc.id='0035000002hLlbUAAS'
UNION
SELECT rsc1.id,rsc1.Name,rsc1.spouse,lvl+1 AS lvl FROM family_tree1_hierarchy AS fth
INNER JOIN main_table AS rsc1 ON fth.id=rsc1.spouse
UNION
SELECT rsc2.id,rsc2.Name,rsc2.spouse,lvl+1 AS lvl FROM family_tree1_hierarchy AS fth2
INNER JOIN main_table AS rsc2 ON fth2.id=rsc2.Father
UNION
SELECT rsc3.id,rsc3.Name,rsc3.spouse,lvl+1 AS lvl FROM family_tree1_hierarchy AS fth3
INNER JOIN main_table AS rsc3 ON fth3.id=rsc3.Mother
)
SELECT * FROM family_tree1_hierarchy
```

Answer (score 1):

**Suggested fix**:
Use just `lvl` instead of `lvl+1` in the 2nd `UNION` part of the query (where it finds the spouse).

**Why the above works and why it fails with `lvl+1`**:
The original query starts with (the non-recursive part) a single person (let's call her Alex) and assigns `0 AS lvl` to her:

```
WITH RECURSIVE family_tree1_hierarchy AS
( SELECT rsc.id,rsc.Name, rsc.spouse, 0 AS lvl 
  FROM main_table AS rsc
  WHERE rsc.i d= '0035000002hLlbUAAS'
  ...
```

It then proceeds (the 3 recursive parts) to find spouses and children.

The problem appears when the first person (or some person found later) has a spouse (let's call him Bob). The spouse is assigned `lvl + 1` (so 1 if the first person has a spouse). It then proceeds (on the next iteration) to find that Bob has a spouse as well (yeah, it's the already found Alex!
But according to the cte, it assigns to newly found Alex (which is a duplicate) the level of Bob plus 1, so this Alex gets 2 as `lvl`.

The crucial bit is that this (duplicate) row has the same name and id and all other details as the original Alex, except for `lvl` which is now 2 instead of 0. So the row is added to the CTE results and we proceed to the next iteration.

We then find Bob again (as spouse of Alex-2) and we assign him 3 as lvl. And it goes on. The CTE produces rows:

```
Alex 0
Bob  1
Alex 2
Bob  3
Alex 4
Bob  5
...
```

until it hits the 1001 iterations threshold and errors.

Our fix works by not increasing level when we find a spouse (only for children). So we still assign Alex 0, but Bob gets 0 as well. When we find Alex again in the next iteration (as spouse of Bob-0) she gets Alex-0 so the row is not added to the CTE results (because we use `UNION` so no duplicates are added) and the cycle breaks.